# Apache2 request flow

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, apache2, lamp

I'm trying to determine the order in which apache processes all of the following. Can you please confirm or deny that this is accurate? Note, this implies `mod_cache`, `mod_rewrite`, `mod_ssl`, and `mod_php` installed.

1. Is SSL? (if yes, decrypt then go to 3)
2. Page in cache? (if yes, load it from cache & jump to 9)
3. Apply `.htaccess` (and any/all rewrite rules contained)
4. Check if requested file (eg `/index.php`) exists. (If yes, go to 5)
5. Check if extension (eg `.php`) is serviced by another module -- here we assume `mod_php`. If yes, go to 6, if no, go to 7
6. PHP module called & passed the source of the file. When finished, goes to 8
7. Read file from disk & go to 8
8. Is file cache-able? If yes, insert into cache & go to 9
9. Set MIME type & return the content
10. Write Apache logs

Comment: I believe it'd need to do the SSL check before checking the cache, as the URL is part of the SSL package.

Comment: set mime type in 9 is not quite accurate. The mime type is sent in the headers along with the content, but it is decided upon by the file extension or the handler (such as PHP), so it's potentially set before it's returned as part of the headers.

Comment: Dorian -- I think it's accurate where it is... the mime type is bubbled up from php (or any other interpreter that was called) & then passed back up through to Apache.